# Can keypaths be encoded in Swift?

Tags: swift, keypaths

Is there anyway to encode and decode a keypath in Swift? Or convert to a string and back?

Comment: No they do not conform to Codable and there is to my knowledge no other general conversion methods available.

Comment: The closest I can think of is something like an Objective C selector. A named "selector" of a method, which is viable even if the object's instance variable layout changes